# Global constrained optimization specification in R

Tags: r, linear-programming

I am trying to set up a global constrained optimization in R.

The experiment data might look like

```
set.seed(123)
data.frame(main.goal = abs(rnorm(100)),
                     minor.goal.1 = abs(rnorm(100)),
                     minor.goal.2 = abs(rnorm(100))) -> d2optim

mean(sort(d2optim$minor.goal.1,
                    decreasing = TRUE)[1:20]) -> minor.goal.1.treshhold
mean(sort(d2optim$minor.goal.2,
                    decreasing = TRUE)[1:20]) -> minor.goal.2.treshhold
```

Where I would like to find indexes (`ind`) of 20 rows that

**EDIT**

- maximzes `mean(d2optim$main.goal[ind])`
- and `mean(d2optim$minor.goal.1[ind]) >= 0.3 minor.goal.1.treshhold`
- and `mean(d2optim$minor.goal.2[ind]) >= 0.5 minor.goal.2.treshhold`

**END EDIT**

Is there a way to use any linear progamming packages such as lpSolve instead of grid checking every $\choose{100,20}$ configuration and then sorting them out? Like

```
all_configuration_of_indexes <- combn(100, 20) # doesn't fit in RAM
for( i in 1:length(all_configuration_of_indexes) ) {
   i <- all_configuration_of_indexes[[i]]
   if ( mean(d2optim$minor.goal.1[i]) >= 0.3 minor.goal.1.treshhold &
        mean(d2optim$minor.goal.2[i]) >= 0.5 minor.goal.2.treshhold) {
      res[[i]] <- mean(d2optim$major.goal[i])
   } else {
      res[[i]] <- 0
   }
}
res[[which(max(unlist(res) = unlist(res))]]
```

**I am looking fot the optimal sub-set of 100 rows that give the maximal mean of 1 variable but their mean of rest 2 variables are not less than `0.3 * minor.goal.1.treshhold nor 0.5 * minor.goal.2.treshhold`**

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for `max(d2optim$main.goal[d2optim$minor.goal.1 >= (0.3 * minor.goal.1.threshold & d2optim$minor.goal.2 >= (0.5 * minor.goal.2.threshlold)]` ?

Comment: @Tensibai sory I have edited my question. I meant `mean`s

Comment: Just to ensure I understand properly, you're looking for 20 rows in the 100, non contiguous, right ?

Comment: (I assume `lm` from `stats` package is what you're looking for, but it's only a guess as I'm not statistician)

Comment: lm is for linear model :P and I am looking fot the optimal sub-set of 100 rows that give the maximal mean of 1 variable but their mean of rest 2 variables are not less than `0.3 * minor.goal.1.treshhold nor 0.5 * minor.goal.2.treshhold`

Comment: Yes, sorry, as said I'm not statistician, I can think of a convoluted approach and I'll give it a try, but I'm pretty sure someone will come with a better answer :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not expert in linear programming and don't know how to implement it in R but that is what I think. I see it as integer linear programming problem modeled as follows:

x1, ..., x100 - logical (that is integer between 0 and 1) variables where xi indicates if we take i-th row of data.

objective function:

x1*d2optim$main.goal[1] + ... + x100*d2optim$main.goal[100] -> max

constraints:

0 <= x1, ..,. x100 <= 1

x1 + ... + x100 = 20

x1*d2optim$minor.goal.1[1] + ... + x100*d2optim$minor.goal.1[100] >= c1

x1*d2optim$minor.goal.2[1] + ... + x100*d2optim$minor.goal.2[100] >= c2

Instead of means we can take sums everywhere and c1, c2 are constatns adequate to your problem specification.

Comment: That's the solution :) Now I know how to use `lpSolve` then. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with:

```
# create an index withe the row meeting condition 2 and 3
idx <- d2optim$minor.goal.1 >= 0.3*minor.goal.1.treshhold & d2optim$minor.goal.2 >= 0.5*minor.goal.2.treshhold

# get the index of rownmubers with the highest values for the `main.goal` variable
rownames(d2optim[idx,][order(-d2optim2$main.goal),][1:20,])
```

which gives you an index of the rownumbers that match your criteria:

```
[1] "97"  "44"  "57"  "98"  "95"  "43"  "29"  "46"  "100" "64"  "74"  "19"  "36"  "75"  "1"   "15"  "20"  "48"  "31"  "13"
```

Because you now have a row index with the highest values for `mail.goal` which also meet the other two conditions, this means that the mean of these values is maximized as well.

Comment: @MarcinKosiński wow, that's harsh commenting twice in 20 mins for someone wishing to choose the best combination in `5.359834e+20` possibilities... Look at the edit history, you'll see the edit was just precision on the first answer matching your original question, probably unrelated to your first comment...

Comment: @MarcinKosiński I answered your initial question. After you updated your question, my answer became incorrect. But downvoting because I didn't immediately improve the answer, seems a bit harsh to me. Especially considering the fact that you are asking to run an optimisation on `535983370403809656832` (see `choose(100, 20)`) possible combinations.